# Firefox restarts flash movie if enclosing DIV class changes

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-ui, firefox

I have a flash movie (simple video player) that is nested within a `DIV`, which is itself nested in a jQueryUI-Draggable `DIV`. Thus `flash-object < div < div.ui-draggable`

Now when I dynamically add/remove a class to the draggable DIV (in this case `minimized` which gives it a smaller size), Firefox (both 3.6 and 4 Win & Mac) will **always** restart the flash movie, which also restarts the video playing in that movie.

Webkit, Opera and even IE (Trident) don't give me that issue.

To clarify: I embed the flash object with the jQuery SWFObject plugin, `wmode` is `opaque`, and all the CSS declarations use absolute pixel dimensions, no `%` or `ems` involved.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your `minimized` class triggers something that requires the CSS boxes for the `<div>` to be rebuilt.  And then you're running into https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90268

Comment: Yeah I also came across this bug (first logged in 2001!) but I wish I knew what CSS properties work and which don't. Will try around a little.

Comment: As far as which work and which don't...  It varies slightly by version, but look for instances of NS_STYLE_HINT_FRAMECHANGE and nsChangeHint_ReconstructFrame in http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/nsStyleStruct.cpp -- whatever properties trigger those will trigger this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came across the CSS value on the enclosing `<div/>` that caused the Flash instance to be redrawn: it was the `overflow` property (which I changed to `hidden`).
Worked out a slightly different CSS solution and everything went fine. Thanks for the hints, guys!